# WordPress Query Posts by URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I know what Im looking to do but need some help with the syntax.

I send out an email with a list of posts displying in the email. The email is generated dynamically before going out using wp_mail.

What I need to do is be able to click a link in the email that will open the website, query the post ID's and open them up in the CPT Archive page.

EDIT:: Actually Ill be opening this on a single custom post type where I will be fetching different headers and footers so, will build an additional query within the template.

The CPS is 'aparrtments'.

So looking for something like :

```
domain.com/apartments/?&ID=1,&ID=2,&ID=3 etc etc
```

Can anyone assist?

BR

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking into syntax only, then the url should have an array of ID's. For example:

```
domain.com/appartments/?ID[]=1&ID[]=2&ID[]=5
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just opens the archive.php and lists the first 10 as normal.

Comment: again, this is only how you get the IDs into the view. Then in the archive.php loop, you'd need to define you own loop that selects only the IDs you are interested in. please take a look at: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/168111

Comment: Exactly, i know what Im trying to do. Lets say I find a way to build a string of ID's from the selected posts that are added into the email. How would I then get that into the posts__in parameter.